# Config.LOGD is deprecated

Tags: android

In android.util.Config, the Config.LOGD, Config.LOGV are now deprecated. Can you please tell me how to refactor my code to in order to get rid of the warnings compiler generated?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Config.DEBUG(true in Debug mode) instead of Config.LOGD.

Comment: When will Config.DEBUG be true and when it will be false? Does it determine by the Manifest file? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Config.DEBUG is deprecated use BuildConfig.DEBUG instead.

See the Google I/O App for Android (iosched) source code for reference on how to make logging more consistent throughout your Android application.
http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/util/LogUtils.java

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Robby means it. See the explanation of open source code.

```
public final class Config
{
    /**
     * If this is a debug build, this field will be true.
     */
    public static final boolean DEBUG = ConfigBuildFlags.DEBUG;
```

PS: I just want to set the above words as comment, but I don't know how to set as comments, so I can only set as another answer.